# What is the proper way to config multimaster on postgresql db's via SymmetricDS?

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

I'm tryig to config multimaster replication between separated postgresql db's. The best non-commercial solution I found is SymmetricDS, but I can't figure out how to config it. Its documentation says alot about abstract concepts, but after reading it I still don't understand what I actually have to do. Maybe there are someone who had had the same probleme and could tell me in general steps how I can make this thing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest version. Then follow the step-by-step quick guide from the first chapter http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/tutorials.html#_demo on how to establish a two node replication. When it started working add a column to one of the tables, recreate the triggers and see how it gets synced. Then create a new table, declare a new trigger for it, associate it to an existing router, restart and enjoy it gets syncing.